# Grizzly multithread methon invocation from Filter

Tags: multithreading, ejb, grizzly

i developed a TCP Server using Grizzly. I used two Filters:

- one to manage the protocol(recognise messages)
- one to invoke a remote server (using RMI).

Unfortunately now it works using only one thread per connection.
I want to ask if is possible to asynchronous invoke remote methods managing the results.
Does anyone have a solution? Is it possible?

Thanks
R

Comment: It might be good to post some example code of what you've tried.

Comment: following up on grizzly mailing list